# Make [IFFT] a synonym of [FFT]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Introduction: The FFT is an algorithm that computes the DFT and the inverse DFT. Many computing environments and libraries have a function FFT and another function IFFT. These compute the DFT and inverse DFT using the FFT algorithm. There is no such thing as the IFFT algorithm. It's one algorithm, the transform direction is dictated by slightly different twiddling of input data and usually a normalization in the inverse transform.

Therefore, [ifft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifft) is redundant.

There are currently 221 questions tagged with [ifft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifft), all of them are also tagged with [fft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fft).

So far it has been used by people applying the `ifft` command in MATLAB or Python. These questions are more meaningfully tagged with [fft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fft). (Actually, most of the questions tagged with either FFT or IFFT should actually be tagged with [dft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dft), since they're not about the algorithm but about the concept or the application of the DFT, but I'm not going to start that uphill battle.)

I have already edited the tag info and excerpt to indicate that [fft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fft) should be used instead.

I have created a tag synonym suggestion for [fft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fft) to make [ifft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ifft) a synonym. If you have 2500 reputation and 5 points in [fft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fft) you can [vote for it here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fft/synonyms).

Comment: They are inverses if each other with different applications. I think you need a stronger argument

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks, I've added a wall of text, I hope that clarifies my reasoning. I thought this was obvious. :/

Comment: @CrisLuengo I only suggested it because you had picked up a couple of downvotes at the time.  As for being obvious - it might be obvious to you and to me, but for someone who has not had any exposure to Fourier and time vs frequency domain, it is not going to be obvious, hence the reason to expand the justification.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I didn't think that people that didn't understand the tag would care to vote. Apparently I was wrong. :)

Comment: @pnuts That is a solution, I guess. I’ll do a couple every now and again to avoid spamming the active page too much. Do you think we should add a “please use FFT tag instead” note to the IFFT tag? Or is that something frowned upon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The synonym suggestion now has a net 3 approvals and an adequate number of qualified users to add a deciding fourth vote. If subject matter experts choose not to vote for the synonym then the synonym should not be created.